# ElasticSearch Java API Client returning same document multiple times in response

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Elasticsearch Java API Client but getting duplicate documents in the response.

Basically, I am trying to fetch documents from MyDocument index, which are in ON mode and have a certain tag from elastic. But the query returns duplicate results. I am getting the same documents twice. I have searched for solution on web but not able to get a solution for this. What is wrong with the below query?
Most of the results on stack overflow shows solutions for High Level REST Client which is now deprecated.

```
        SearchResponse<MyDocument> response = elasticsearchClient.search(fn -> fn
                .query(query -> query
                        .bool(bq -> bq
                                .must(
                                    List.of(
                                            new Query.Builder()
                                            .term(t -> t
                                                    .field(mode.keyword)
                                                    .value("ON")
                                                ).build()
                                            ,new Query.Builder()
                                            .matchPhrase(phrase -> phrase
                                                    .field("tags")                    
                                                    .query("My tag")
                                                )
                                                .build()
                                            )
                                )
                        ))
                , MyDocument.class);
```

Comment: I believe that you have documents duplicate.

Comment: @rabbitbr No the documents coming in response have same id. also, i cross checked on kibana